# Change in return position throws variable not defined error

Tags: python

I came across this problem while learning how to return a sorted list in Python. When I write the code this way

```
def func(A):
   return A
A = sorted([4,5,6,7,2,1]) 
print(A)
```

It sorts the list perfectly and returns `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.
But when I change the position of `return A` to

```
def func(A):
 A = sorted([4,5,6,7,2,1]) 
 return A
print(A)
```

It throws `name 'A' is not defined` error.

I Googled why it's showing variable not defined, and the first answer was to see whether I haven't misspelled it and accessed it after defining it, and that I did.

Comment: Do you know what functions are, and why we define them? In neither case do you ever *call* your function, so everything within the `def` might as well not be there.

Comment: You have `print (A)`, but the program does not know what `A` is ?? It has not been defined.  You program does not call func(), so A is never created.

Comment: @CrazyChucky So like....why is it showing error when i change the position

Comment: In your first example, you define A as `A = sorted([4,5,6,7,2,1])`. In your second example, you do not define A at all.

Comment: You should learn about the scope of variables.

Comment: @ScottC So we have to define "A in this case" after we use return ?

Comment: You never actually "used" return, because you never called your function. The code within your function definition was never executed. (Though as Kris points out, even if it were, that would only define `A` within the function, not outside it.)

Comment: so another example where we use `def list(A):` then we `return A` and then feed whatever calculation we want to assign A before printing it ?

Comment: I don't think any single, concise answer will help you here. You need an entire Python tutorial. (I would suggest the [official one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).)

Comment: @CrazyChucky i removed the `return A` line from my code but it still says A is not defined. Any resource i can look at to understand whats going on ? edit: Understood will checkout the docs

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to summarize what has been hinted to you in the comments using examples.

##### the function is never executed

Your code:

```
def func(A):
    return A
A = sorted([4,5,6,7,2,1]) 
print(A)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
A = sorted([4,5,6,7,2,1]) 
print(A)
```

Although defined, the function is never used, so you could write:

```
def func(A):               # defined but never executed
    return 'unicorn'       #
A = sorted([4,5,6,7,2,1]) 
print(A)
```

This wouldn't change a thing.

Now doing the same with your second code:

```
def func(A):                    # defined
    A = sorted([4,5,6,7,2,1])   # but never
    return A                    # executed
print(A)
```

becomes:

```
print(A)
```

and python rightfully asks: "What is A?"

##### functions have a different scope

You **should** avoid using the same variable names inside and outside of a function. You **can**, and python is very good at knowing which one's which, but humans not as much, so be explicit.

What you likely want is:

```
def func(lst):          # func takes one parameter, lst
    return sorted(lst)  # does stuff on it and returns an output

A = [4,5,6,7,2,1]

print(func(A))
```

##### adding confusion: global scope and mutability

Now, functions **can also** access the outer scope, provided the variable is not also defined inside the function (property 1) and modify an external object if it is mutable (property 2).

Here is an example, but you should really avoid this kind of structure as it is unexplicit:

```
def func():
    A.sort()  # A is undefined in the function
              # let's try to grab it from the outer scope

A = [4,5,6,7,2,1]

func() # now A is sorted

print(A)
# [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: I stand corrected. An impressively concise and thorough breakdown of all the issues the question raised.